# IOS Swift. Time since date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want the number of months and days since a given date which is given by a string.

d is a string of a date

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(d)
    startTime = date?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

I would ideally like the months,days,minutes since the date but I will work that part once I get passed this error. The compiler is complaining about the last line.

Thanks

Comment: Is `startTime` declared as optional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use an `NSCalendar` to compute a difference in terms of months and days.  Example:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2014-9-15") {
    let components = calendar.components([ .Month, .Day ],
        fromDate: startDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
    let months = components.month
    let days = components.day
    print("It's been \(months) months and \(days) days.")
}
```

Output (on 2014-01-05):

```
It's been 3 months and 21 days.
```

Comment: I believe the Swift update has changed allot of this. Mainly that the or operator no longer works with the enums. Great solution! thanks